# My <p:selectOneMenu> doesn't return any value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a form with three p:selectOneMenu but when i click the button to debug, the ManagedBean doesn't have any value. Someone help me?

The form

```
<h:form id="form">      
             <p:commandButton value="Salvar" icon="ui-icon-document" class="botaoDataTable"
                actionListener="#{cenarioBean.cadastrarAvaliacaoDeArea}" process="@this"/>

             <h:outputText style="margin-left:2%;" id="probabilidadeSucesso" value="Probabilidade de Sucesso: #{controleBean.calcularProbabilidadeDeSucesso()}" />

             <p:panelGrid style="float:left; margin-left:2%; margin-top:1%; width:70%;" styleClass="semBorda">  
                <p:row>
                    <p:column><h:outputText style="font-size:90%;" value="Distância entre o local de perfuração e o poço produtor mais próximo" /></p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:30% !important;">                    
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="distanciaAv" value="#{cenarioBean.avaliacaoArea.distanciaPocoProdutor}" class="componentePF text">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha uma Opção" itemDisabled="true" noSelectionOption="true" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Menor ou Igual a 2,5 Km" itemValue="A" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Até 10 Km" itemValue="B" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Entre 10 Km e 50 Km" itemValue="C" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Acima de 50 Km" itemValue="D" /> 
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:row>
                    <p:column><h:outputText style="font-size:90%;" value="O local de perfuração pertence à mesma formação geológica do poço produtor" /></p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:30% !important;">                    
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="formGeo" value="#{cenarioBean.avaliacaoArea.mesmaFormacaoGeologica}" class="componentePF text">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha uma Opção" itemDisabled="true" noSelectionOption="true" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sim" itemValue="S"  /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Não" itemValue="N" /> 
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:row>
                    <p:column><h:outputText style="font-size:90%;" value="Há evidências positivas para prospecção" /></p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:30% !important;">                    
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="prospecpos" value="#{cenarioBean.avaliacaoArea.evidenciasProspeccao}" class="componentePF text">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha uma Opção" itemDisabled="true" noSelectionOption="true" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sim" itemValue="S" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Não" itemValue="N" /> 
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
             </p:panelGrid>

         </h:form>
```

When i click the  on debug my object doesn't have any value. It has null setted to strings.

ManagedBean

```
  private AvaliacaoDeArea avaliacaoArea = new AvaliacaoDeArea();
//...

public String calcularProbabilidadeDeSucesso() {
        String aux = avaliacaoArea.getDistanciaPocoProdutor();
        aux += avaliacaoArea.getMesmaFormacaoGeologica();
        aux += avaliacaoArea.getEvidenciasProspeccao();

        System.out.println(aux+"\n");
        return aux;
    }


    public AvaliacaoDeArea getAvaliacaoArea() { 
        return avaliacaoArea;
    }

    public void setAvaliacaoArea(AvaliacaoDeArea avaliacaoArea) {
        this.avaliacaoArea = avaliacaoArea;
    }
```

POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AvaliacaoDeArea", schema="somore")
public class AvaliacaoDeArea implements Serializable, SampleEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idAvaliacaoDeArea;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idCenario")
    private Cenario cenario;

    private String distanciaPocoProdutor;

    private String mesmaFormacaoGeologica;

    private String evidenciasProspeccao;

    private String probabilidadeSucesso;

    /***************************************/
    /************** Construtor *************/
    /***************************************/

    public AvaliacaoDeArea() {

    }

    /***************************************/
    /********** Getters e Setters **********/
    /***************************************/
```

Comment: Are you using Salvar button to submit form? If yes, why do you have process="@this" on it?

Comment: I see now i had used the wrong term.

Comment: Great. always check your process and update attributes when submitting.

Comment: Okay! Do you have any idea of what's happening?

Comment: yes. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces

Comment: @hugodeiró: if you use something, at least know the basics of how things work. Save you and usa lot of time